# Can't make closest() and find() work

Tags: jquery, closest

Can't make `closest()` and `find()` work:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('a.favorites_save') .live('click', function(e) {
        thisObj = this;
        e.preventDefault();
        var link = $(this).attr('href')
        alert(link)
        $.get(link, function() {
            $(thisObj).find('a.favorites_delete:first').show();
            $(thisObj).hide();
        });
        return false;
    });

    $('a.favorites_delete') .live('click', function(e) {
        thisObj = this;
        e.preventDefault();
        var link = $(this).attr('href')
        $.get(link, function(data) { 
            $(thisObj).closest('a.favorites_save:first').show();
            $(thisObj).hide();
        });
        return false;
    });
</script>
```

HTML

```
<ul class="action-buttons">
    <li><a href="#link" class="portfolio">Add to portfolio</a></li>
    <span class="favorites_status"></span>
    <li><a class="favourites favorites_save" style="display:none;" href="/_web_includes/faves/reference/569">Add to Favourites</a></li>
    <li class="current"><a class="favourites favorites_delete" href="/_web_includes/faves/reference/569/delete">Remove Favourite</a></li>
```

When I press Remove Favourite it hides a link but `show()` doesn't work, the same with `find()` method. The HTML code repeated in the HTML sources just can't bring it all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are referencing the .find() and .closest() from within $(this) object.  .closest() will only find parents to this object, while .find() will find children of this object.  If you want a global selection, just do this...

```
$("a.favorites_save:first")
```

and this for delete...

```
$("a.favorites_delete:first")
```

Comment: will it always select the first global a.favorites_save? I need to show/hide related selectors

Comment: This selector will select the first global a.favorites_save.  If you need to select the reference in <ul class="action-buttons" > you can do something like @ShaneBlake suggested.
$(thisObj).closest("ul").find('favorites_delete');

Comment: yes this is solution, I was about to answer my question just my reputation is too low so i have to wait 8 hours. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Because your links are inside a `<li>`, both '.find()' and '.closest()' will never see them.  Those two only work up and down the same branch of the tree...

You need to do something like `.closest('action-buttons').find('favorites_delete')` to get it to work...

Answer (score 0):

The solution is something like that

```
$(thisObj).closest("ul").find('favorites_delete');
```

Just need up higher on the tree